# Extracting text between end and start of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I'm looking to extract the telephone number:

I am using NodeJS / ExpressJS / Request / Cheerio.

This code will be part of a web crawler.

```html
<div class="info">
  <h3> Home </h3>
  <p>
    <strong> Tel: </strong>
    01345 000000
    <strong> Fax: </strong>
    01345 000000
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
```

I'm currently only able to retrieve the text "Tel:".

Here's the progress I've made:

```js
$('div.info p').filter(function() {
  $(this).find('strong').filter(function() {
    var phonenumber = $(this).text();
    console.log(phonenumber);
  });
});
```

Comment: are you not able to change the HTML at all so that it may be something like `<p>Tel: <strong> 01345 000000</strong></p>`

Comment: The Tel number is quoted because you copied from the Google Chrome element inspector right? If so, please remove them from your question.

Comment: It's not my HTML, I'm crawling a customers website.

Comment: The Tel number is quoted in the source code yes, not on the website. I'll amend the question.

Comment: @AlexLegg Urge you to please let us know with comment(s) under the answer(s) if you have made significant changes to the original question. Also, do you need the fax number as well??

Comment: Will do. I didn't know I'll be needing scripts so I'll need to figure out how to add them to my crawl. Nope, I don't need the fax, I also need the address, website and email but I didn't want to bombard you guys with too much.

Comment: @AlexLegg Aah ok.. cool! You can ask more questions in case you need to.. that's what SO is all about :) All the best with your work!

Comment: I think I might have to haha, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var temp = $('p');
temp = temp.text().trim();
temp = temp.substring(4, 22);

$('.info').html(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">
  <h3> Home </h3>
  <p>
    <strong> Tel: </strong>
    01346 000000
    <strong> Fax: </strong>
    01345 000000
  </p>
  <p>
</p>
```

Comment: Kudos to you for simplicity and out of the box success.

Comment: @AlexLegg I am happy that this works for you. Now the advanced logic stuff is up to you :-) because you know, you're a programmer right?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the text between the first `<p>` then have applied substring on it as something like, substring of first Occurence of **:** using `getPosition(str, m, i)` function and  'F' character. Then trimming whatever the result is.

```js
$('div.info p:first').filter(function() {
  $(this).filter(function() {
    var phonenumber = $(this).text();
    //console.log(phonenumber);
    alert(phonenumber.substring(getPosition(phonenumber, ':', 1)+1, phonenumber.indexOf('F')).trim());
  });
});

function getPosition(str, m, i) {
   return str.split(m, i).join(m).length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <h3> Home </h3>
  <p>
    <strong> Tel: </strong>
    01345 000000
    <strong> Fax: </strong>
    01345 000000
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your phone numbers are not enclosed into `<strong>` tags. From your HTML one way to extract them would be to use some sort of regular expression, for example:

```
var regexp = /"([\d ]+)"/g;
var text = $('div.info p').text();
var phone_nr = regexp.exec(text);
while (phone_nr != null) {
    console.log(phone_nr[1]);
    phone_nr = regexp.exec(text);
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1L4ux5g/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the text content of the `strong` element. You can use the `nextSibling` property for selecting the next sibling nodes.

```
$('div.info p strong').each(function() {
    var phonenumber = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
    console.log(phonenumber);
  });
});
```

It should be noted that when the `strong` element doesn't have a next sibling the above code will throw an error. You can pass the node to jQuery/Cheerio and it handles the edge cases behind the scenes:

```
var phonenumber = $.trim($(this.nextSibling).text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vs3psmnq/